# How to close Bootstrap modal on submit in Aurelia

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-modal, aurelia

I tried many ways but I couldn't find the solution.
This is my .ts code

```
 postData(object) {    
    httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:55265/api/*****', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(object),
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"       
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);  
        if (data == true) {
          alert(`Saved!`); 
          // here I want to close my model 
        } else {
          alert(`Error!`); 
        }
      });
  }
```

This is my .html file.This is how I add modal

```
<div id="AddNews" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
</div>
```

Comment: Make a function then call after `alert();`  Implement closing logic in the function

Comment: share your full code to us.You should use `data-dismiss="modal"` property

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.modal('hide')` to an element with id.

```
document.getElementById('AddNews').modal('hide');
```

So your final code would look like

```
postData(object) {    
  httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:55265/api/*****', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(object),
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"       
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);  
    if (data == true) {
      alert(`Saved!`); 
      document.getElementById('AddNews').modal('hide');
    } else {
      alert(`Error!`); 
    }
  });
}
```

Since your using Aurelia, can you try adding a reference to the dom element? Something like

```
<div id="AddNews" class="modal fade" role="dialog" ref="newsRef">
</div>

class ViewModel { 

    //access here
    this.newsRef.modal('hide');

}
```

Comment: I got this error : _[ts] Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'._

Comment: _Unhandled rejection TypeError: _this.newsRef.modal is not a function_

Comment: Mind creating a fiddle @Lakmi?

Answer (score -1):

```
postData(object) {    
    httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:55265/api/*****', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(object),
      headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"       
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);  
        if (data == true) {
          alert(`Saved!`); 
          $("#AddNews").modal(hide);
        } else {
          alert(`Error!`); 
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I wrote this code in typescript so I couldn't do this way

Comment: Avoid only code answers. Include some text to explain it.